# Adding a custom UIBarButtonItem to a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, button, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to have a large plus button as a right bar button, the code below worked while it was in a storyboard, but after moving everything to xib files and separate .swift files, this was the only thing that broke.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
button.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(GroupNavViewController.onCreate))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40)], forState: .Normal)
```

The UINavigationController is its own .swift file with no xib file.

I can't figure out why it worked in the storyboard, but now it doesn't.

Ideally, I'd like to have a large plus button (as the normal font size seems a bit too small)

Comment: what did you put in the xib files? navigation bar?

Comment: the navigation controller contains another view controller, but has no xib file for itself. https://github.com/gomeow/BillSplitter/blob/master/BillSplitter/GroupNavViewController.swift#L20-L26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does work for me. i just got rid of target action so i don't have to implement it. all done in code. no storyboards and no xibs.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?
let viewController = ViewController();

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40)], forState: .Normal)

}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I was trying to add the button to the navigation controller, not the view controller it contained.

Answer (score 1):

> The UINavigationController is its own .swift file with no xib file.

Make this Button in the UIViewController class and not in your UINavigationController. So move the same code to your UIViewController.

Comment: That did not work, the title does not show up that way either